# How to upgrade python to 3.11 version to my flask project?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, upgrade, python-3.11

Currently, python3.9 is being used and we want to upgrade to the latest version

In my flask project, I checked out to main branch and have upgraded my python to v3.11
I verified it by python3 --version.
Next, I have created a new virtual environment named myenv
python3.11 -m venv myenv
Later I activated it.
source myenv/bin/activate
And then, I did
pip install -r requirements.txt
I was surprised as 7k+ new files were added, I have ran the pytest and they were fine. My question is should I raise my MR with these huge number of changes (7k+ new files added!)?

Answer (score 0):

No. These are dependencies of your project and should not be in your git. Likely git has picked up your newly created venv (named myenv). You should instead gitignore the myenv folder.

Comment: Hi there! do you mean like for python version upgrade, no changes needs to be done in existing repository !! If the individual devs can upgrade python versions in their local, will that be fine? If possible can you please detail me step by step process !

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by python upgrade. But in general, if you want your code to be supported by a certain version of python (say 3.11), you only need to make changes to the codebase that are either no longer supported by the targeted version, or make use of new features from the target version. If all your tests pass on 3.11, i believe you should be good.  If you want to support multiple python versions, run your test suite on all the target versions, preferably using tools like tox.